# How to cache masterpage settings?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am using one master page.In that I am registering java scripts and checking some session conditions for every page.

I Don't want this one to be called for each and every page.It takes some time to execute the code.

Is there a way to avoid this repetitive execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to keep checking the session conditions - as they are per-user, there's no way to guarantee that any one request is coming from the same user without checking sessions/cookies.

As to the script stuff - could you make those declarative (in the mark-up) rather than in the code-behind?

A possible alternative is to look into "donut caching" where you cache most of the page, but leave those areas of the page that change on a "per user" basis out of the cache.

Scott Guthrie has a good post on this:

> [Tip/Trick: Implement "Donut Caching" with the ASP.NET 2.0 Output Cache Substitution Feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/28/tip-trick-implement-donut-caching-with-the-asp-net-2-0-output-cache-substitution-feature.aspx)

Comment: Excellent Answer!! 

I shall try with that and get back you soon.